# Powershell trim string on second blank

Tags: string, powershell, trim

I'm currently using `-replace " .*" -creplace '(?<=\w)([A-Z])', ' $1'` to convert a string in the format `FirstnameLastname FirstnameLastname FirstnameLastname` to `Firstname Lastname`.
Now the input format changed to `Firstname Lastname Firstname Lastname Firstname Lastname`.
Any ideas how I can convert this to `Firstname Lastname` (Trim it on the second blank in the string)?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Answer (score 1):

Split on whitespace, keep the first two strings and then throw away the rest:

```
$first,$last,$null = 'Firstname Lastname Firstname Lastname Firstname Lastname' -split '\s+',3
$name = "$first $last"
```